# htaccess Redirection - domain.com/folder to website.com/folder

Tags: .htaccess, dns, url-rewriting, redirect, subdirectory

I have what I thought would be a simple question but I suppose I'm missing something.

I have a website with two domain names associated with it. What I'd like to do is modify my .htaccess file so that anyone trying to access a particular folder is redirected to the correct domain name.

For example:

Someone accessing `www.domain.com/folder/` should be redirected to `www.website.com/folder/`, but only for that folder.

What would I have to include in the .htaccess file to do this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

RewriteCond will do the trick. NOTE: I didn't test this verbatim, so it's psuedocodish.

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/folder/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Make sure you check the docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html specifically flags like [QSA] which means to append the query string.

Note the R=301 flag, which will tell the visitor that this is a permanent redirect. There are many other flags you can use...

Comment: I would say `RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !=www.website.com` will be better .. but that depends on circumstances.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me for the project I'm working on but solved another .htaccess issue I was having so much obliged!

Comment: For those curious, I found a workaround using PHP to generate a particular link I needed. The workaround was necessary due to time restrictions and is specific to the proprietary platform I'm working with.